# Ajax check for model update - is there a better solution than timer?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a Rails application I have a situation where I want to update the info on the page once the information in the model is updated.. Is there a better solution that doing it via setimeout /setinterval that are sending requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your app send a javascript message to the app using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) (or similar, like [Private Pub](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub)

1. Javascript would listen (subscribe) for a message
2. Your app sends the message that it's complete
3. Javascript refreshes the content (page refresh or get content from ajax)